# how to find a color representation string in a string in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, wxpython, ipython

example:

```
col_str = 'South Shore Lily Rose 4 Drawer Chest in White Wash'
```

I want to take white alone, we should not hard-code the color string by default it has to identify, how to do this?

Comment: There are three words in that string that can be taken to mean colours, namely *lily*, *rose* and *white*. Do you mean that you want to accept only primary colours or white or black?

Comment: no all colors, i required

Comment: try to avoid variable names that are keywords in python like `str` here!

Comment: recovered. thanks @hiro

Comment: This can be done with somewhat less ambiguity for complete, syntactically simple sentences using natural language processing techniques. However, you're asking about how to work with what I take to be a noun phrase of some kind, which might be difficult to analyse. The simplest thing to do would be a look-up against a (big) list of colour words but words like *aubergine* (which can mean a colour or a food) might still prove difficult to assign correctly. wikipedia has some good collections of colour words, incidentally.

Comment: @BillBell , Yes, even i had a same thought. Thanks for your response.

Comment: I missed wxpython amongst your keywords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have tagged question with wxpython ,I am assuming that you have wxpython and the below code should be useful for you:

```
import wx.lib.colourdb as wb
col_str = 'South Shore Lily Rose 4 Drawer Chest in White Wash'
colr = wb.getColourList()
for x in col_str.split(" "):
    if(x.upper() in colr):
        print(x)
```